# How to Use Delegation to Remove Object from Data Source

Tags: ios, swift

I am programming my first iOS application and am in the process of learning about protocols and delegation. The application is a basic random response generator. When the user shakes the device or taps the screen, a random response should display in a label.

Currently, I have three view controllers embedded in a navigation controller: `MainViewController.swift`, `SettingsViewController.swift`, and `ResponsesViewController.swift`.

I have an array in `MainViewController.swift` that holds the responses. I have successfully been able to pass the data to the third view controller, which is `ResponsesViewController.swift`, which is a table view for displaying the stored responses. I have set my first view controller, `MainViewController` as the delegate for my third view controller, `ResponsesViewController`, and implemented the method where I would like to remove the selected response from the data model (`responses` array).

My problem is when I try deleting a response I get `fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer` in the console. I used `println(responses.count)` to make sure that I was passing the array to the second and third view controllers successfully. I placed the `println(responses.count)` statement in all three view controllers within the methods `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear()`, and `viewDidDisappear()`. This showed that the data was passing successfully as there were 3 objects in the array with each `println()` statement. However, in my delegate, `MainViewController.swift`, I keep getting the error when I try to remove the selected response from the data model. I placed `println(responses.count)` into this method, but it keeps returning `0` and crashing with the error. It is only happening when `func responsesViewController(controller: ResponsesViewController, didDeleteResponseAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` is being called in the delegate (`MainViewController.swift`)

Here is my code:

`MainViewController.swift`

```
var responses: [Response] = []
let response1 = Response(text: "String 1")
let response2 = Response(text: "String 2")
let response3 = Response(text: "String 3")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    responses += [response1, response2, response3]
}

* delegate *
func responsesViewController(controller: ResponsesViewController, didDeleteResponseAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    responses.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}
```

`ResponsesViewController.swift`

```
protocol DeleteResponseDelegate {
func responsesViewController(controller: ResponsesViewController, didDeleteResponseAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        delegate?.responsesViewController(self, didDeleteResponseAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

-EDIT-

It turns out that I was able to fix my issue by simply passing the array from my third view controller back to my first view controller. I was obviously confused about delegation. Here is my updated code where I deleted the item from the array and then passed that array back to the first view controller:

`ResponsesViewController.swift`

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        responses.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        let mainViewController = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as MainViewController
        mainViewController.responses = self.responses
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry if im missing something, but responses is empyt isn't it? ie respnse1 != responses[0]

Comment: @chris I added the code where I inserted three string objects into the array.

Comment: so i gather you pass the data to the other views fine, how are you passing it back?

Comment: Good question. I had assumed that the responses array in MainViewController still held the objects that it was created with. Is that incorrect? Does the data travel across view controllers and only have one instance of the array at all times? That is making sense to me now as to why it would be empty when trying to remove the selected response in the delegate.

Answer (score -1):

From your comment -

> I had assumed that the responses array in MainViewController still
>   held the objects that it was created with. Is that incorrect? Does the
>   data travel across view controllers and only have one instance of the
>   array at all times?

This would be true of an NSArray, which is an object.  Swift arrays are structures, and structures are value types. Value types are copied when they are assigned.

> In fact, all of the basic types in Swift—integers, floating-point
>   numbers, Booleans, strings, arrays and dictionaries—are value types,
>   and are implemented as structures behind the scenes.
>
> All structures and enumerations are value types in Swift. This means
>   that any structure and enumeration instances you create—and any value
>   types they have as properties—are always copied when they are passed
>   around in your code.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/au/jEUH0.l

Comment: I now understand that the array gets copied when it is passed to the next view controller. However, I am still a little confused about that. For instance, let's say the array in my initial view controller has 1 value. Then I pass it to the second view controller where I add a second value to it. Does that mean the array in the initial view controller still has one value while the array in the second view controller has two values until I pass that data back to my initial view controller so that it can have both values?

Comment: Correct.  When you pass an object, it passes a reference to the one instance of the object.  When you pass a value-type (structure, array, integer) then the value is copied, so you end up with a brand-new array with one element to which you add the second element.  This is why using a model object is better design than using properties